# Moment js date time comparison

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, momentjs

I'm using moment.js to format my date time, here I have two date values, and I want to achieve a particular function when one date is greater than the other. I read most of their docs, but didn't find the function to achieve this. I know it will be there.

This is my code:

```
var date_time = 2013-03-24 + 'T' + 10:15:20:12 + 'Z'
var d = moment(date_time).tz('UTC'); // first date 

var now = new Date(),
    dnow = moment(now).tz('UTC'),
    snow = dnow.minute() % 15,
    diffnow = 15 - snow,
    tonow = moment(dnow).add('minute', diffnow),
    ahead30now = moment(tonow).add('minute', 30);

if (d > ahead30now) {
    // allow input time
    console.log('UTC TIME DB', d.format());
} else {

}
```

**Edit**

```
var date_time = req.body.date + 'T' + req.body.time + req.body.timezone; // 2014-03-24T01:15:000
var utc_input_time = moment(date_time).utc(); // 2014-03-24T01:15:000
console.log('utc converted date_time', moment(date_time).utc().format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:SSS"));
var isafter = moment(utc_input_time).isAfter(moment('2014-03-24T01:14:000')); // true
if(isafter === true){
    console.log('is after true');
} else {
    console.log('is after is false');
}
```

Here, I am comparing two dates i.e. `2014-03-24T01:15:000 > 2014-03-24T01:14:000`, expecting that the first one is greater than the second one, but it always goes to the else condition. I don't know why?

Answer (score 701, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [query functions](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/), `isBefore`, `isSame`, and `isAfter`.

But it's a bit difficult to tell exactly what you're attempting.  Perhaps you are just looking to get the difference between the input time and the current time?  If so, consider the [difference function](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/), `diff`.  For example:

```
moment().diff(date_time, 'minutes')
```

A few other things:

- There's an error in the first line:

  ```
    var date_time = 2013-03-24 + 'T' + 10:15:20:12 + 'Z'
  ```

  That's not going to work.  I think you meant:

  ```
    var date_time = '2013-03-24' + 'T' + '10:15:20:12' + 'Z';
  ```

  Of course, you might as well:

  ```
    var date_time = '2013-03-24T10:15:20:12Z';
  ```
- You're using: `.tz('UTC')` incorrectly.  `.tz` belongs to [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/). You don't need to use that unless you're working with other time zones, like `America/Los_Angeles`.

  If you want to parse a value as UTC, then use:

  ```
    moment.utc(theStringToParse)
  ```

  Or, if you want to parse a local value and *convert* it to UTC, then use:

  ```
    moment(theStringToParse).utc()
  ```

  Or perhaps you don't need it at all.  Just because the input value is in UTC, doesn't mean you have to work in UTC throughout your function.
- You seem to be getting the "now" instance by  `moment(new Date())`.  You can instead just use `moment()`.

#### Updated

Based on your edit, I think you can just do this:

```
var date_time = req.body.date + 'T' + req.body.time + 'Z';
var isafter = moment(date_time).isAfter('2014-03-24T01:14:00Z');
```

Or, if you would like to ensure that your fields are validated to be in the correct format:

```
var m = moment.utc(req.body.date + ' ' + req.body.time, "YYYY-MM-DD  HH:mm:ss");
var isvalid = m.isValid();
var isafter = m.isAfter('2014-03-24T01:14:00Z');
```

Answer (score 319):

You should be able to compare them directly.

```
var date = moment("2013-03-24")
var now = moment();

if (now > date) {
   // date is past
} else {
   // date is future
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('.compare').click(function(e) {
  
    var date = $('#date').val();
  
    var now = moment();
    var then = moment(date);
  
    if (now > then) {
      $('.result').text('Date is past');
    } else {
      $('.result').text('Date is future');
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>



<input type="text" name="date" id="date" value="2014-12-18"  placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd">
<button class="compare">Compare date to current date</button>
<br>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: I feel like it's worth explaining that this works because javascript coerces objects to primitives via `Object.prototype.valueOf` which is overridden in the moment prototype to return an epoch timestamp as a number. So this is similar to `now.format('x') > date.format('x')`.

Comment: no its not working... here is what i tried .      // newDate is higher then now's date...so it prints fail in both greaterthen and lessthen conditions                                                      
          const resDate = res.url.expiryDate;
          const newDate = moment(resDate);
          var now = moment().format("DD/MM/YYYY");
          if (now<newDate) {
            console.log("success");
          } else {
            console.log("fail")
          }

Comment: @steve `moment().format("DD/MM/YYYY")` will return a string and then you are comparing alphabetically and then December 1st would come before January 2, because you are leading with days, too. Don't use `format()` if you want to compare the moment objcts directly.

Answer (score 53):

It is important that your datetime is in the correct **ISO format** when using any of the [**momentjs queries**](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/): [`isBefore`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/), [`isAfter`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/), [`isSameOrBefore`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same-or-before/), [`isSameOrAfter`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same-or-after/), [`isBetween`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/)

So instead of 2014-03-24T01:14:000, your datetime should be either:

> **2014-03-24T01:14:00** or **2014-03-24T01:14:00.000Z**

otherwise you may receive the following deprecation warning and the condition will evaluate to false:

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or
>   ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not
>   reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date
>   formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major
>   release. Please refer to
>   http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.

```js
// https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/

const dateIsAfter = moment('2014-03-24T01:15:00.000Z').isAfter(moment('2014-03-24T01:14:00.000Z'));

const dateIsSame = moment('2014-03-24T01:15:00.000Z').isSame(moment('2014-03-24T01:14:00.000Z'));

const dateIsBefore = moment('2014-03-24T01:15:00.000Z').isBefore(moment('2014-03-24T01:14:00.000Z'));

console.log(`Date is After: ${dateIsAfter}`);
console.log(`Date is Same: ${dateIsSame}`);
console.log(`Date is Before: ${dateIsBefore}`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.0/moment.min.js"
></script>
```

Answer (score 36):

Jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/guhokemk/1/

```
 function compare(dateTimeA, dateTimeB) {
    var momentA = moment(dateTimeA,"DD/MM/YYYY");
    var momentB = moment(dateTimeB,"DD/MM/YYYY");
    if (momentA > momentB) return 1;
    else if (momentA < momentB) return -1;
    else return 0;
}

alert(compare("11/07/2015", "10/07/2015"));
```

The method returns 1  if dateTimeA is greater than dateTimeB

The method returns 0 if dateTimeA equals dateTimeB

The method returns -1  if dateTimeA is less than dateTimeB

Answer (score 27):

for date-time comparison, you can use `valueOf` function of the moment which provides milliseconds of the date-time, which is best for comparison:

```js
const date1 = moment('01-02-2020', 'DD-MM-YYYY').valueOf()
const date2 = moment('11-11-2012', 'DD-MM-YYYY').valueOf()

// console.log((date1 > date2 ? 'date1' : 'date2') + " is greater..."  )

if (date1 > date2) {
  console.log("date1 is greater...")
} else {
  console.log("date2 is greater...")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 14):

```
moment(d).isAfter(ahead30now); // true
```

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/

```
if (moment(d).isAfter(ahead30now)) {
    // allow input time
    console.log('UTC TIME DB', d.format());
} else {

}
```

Answer (score 10):

```js
var startDate = moment(startDateVal, "DD.MM.YYYY");//Date format
var endDate = moment(endDateVal, "DD.MM.YYYY");

var isAfter = moment(startDate).isAfter(endDate);

if (isAfter) {
    window.showErrorMessage("Error Message");
    $(elements.endDate).focus();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

pass date to moment like this it will compare and give result.
if you dont want format remove it

```
moment(Date1).format("YYYY-MM-DD") > moment(Date2).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
```

Comment: `Be careful` this is nothing but comparing two string

Comment: @PranoySarkar can you please tell me why we need to be more careful?

Comment: I think the point was that you need to be careful here because you are really comparing strings, not dates when using `.format`. It works in this case because it's year, then month, then day (`"YYYY-MM-DD"`). However, if you had a format of `"MM-DD-YYYY"` or `"DD-MM-YYYY"`, it may not do what you intend (check if one date is greater than another date). For example. `"01-01-2021" > "12-12-1990"` will return `false` because it starts the comparison at the first character, and `0` comes before `1`. So just be careful that it's formatted in a way that would work in all instances.

Answer (score 0):

- Check two dates equal or not using moment js.
- I used **granularity => 'D'** for check date only
  **without time**.

this command working fine for me.

```
moment(date1).isSame(moment(date2), 'D')
```

Answer (score -1):

say if you want to disable past dates in date picker the following code will surely going to help you
disabledDate={(current) => {
return (
current &&
current.format("YYYY-MM-DD") <
moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")
);
}}

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.