# How to do a greater than or equal to with moments (moment.js) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

Basically, I want to do a `myMoment >= yourMoment`. There is no `myMoment.isSameOrAfter` and writing that out combining `isSame` and `.isAfter` is a bit lengthy.

What's the alternative? Convert moment to js date and use `>=` to compare?

Comment: Have you tried a if(!moment1.isBefore(moment2)) ?

Comment: @Donal - well I'm debugging in chrome and noticing myMoment == yourMoment is false, but myMoment.isSame(yourMoment) is true.

Comment: @donal  JavaScript does not support operator overloading, and so relational operators like <, <=, > and >= are actually doing reference comparison.  So, if it "works", it is a complete accident and due to the fact its comparing primitive values for these complex objects.

Comment: @JohnZabroski that's not true, JS is using the valueOf prototype method to compare, so operators like >, >=, < and <= are valid on Moment instances since they will use the valueOf i.e. the timestamps.

Comment: @antoine129 I repeat, it is due to the fact its comparing primitive values for these complex objects. valueOf is how JavaScript gets the primitive value.  It is not a guarantee that this value is even a number.

Comment: @JohnZabroski I repeat, it is guaranteed to be a Number in the case of Moment.js: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/ and see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600856/moment-js-date-time-comparison#comment79617624_22601019

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Okay, I just went with the moment.js [`.diff()` function.](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)

`myMoment.diff(yourMoment) >= 0`

Close enough.

Comment: What do you mean, "close enough"?  It's exactly the right behavior.  If you want isOnOrAfter, just add a function to the Moment prototype.

Comment: It's worth mentioning diff returns the difference in milliseconds, so if you're thinking about expanding this by saying next week is diff(yourMoment) >= 7 you will fail.  Also, don't just add milliseconds in a day,because time zones, etc. will mess you up.

Comment: follow up to @NickSteele's comment, you can use it for different time measures with the second param. e.g: (myMoment.diff(yourMoment, 'minutes') >= 15) or (myMoment.diff(yourMoment, 'days') >= 7)

Answer (score 217):

You can use the [`isSameOrAfter`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same-or-after/) method in momentjs:

```
moment1.isSameOrAfter(moment2);
```

Comment: Only available in moment.js version 2.10.7+

Comment: FYI: `isSameOrBefore` is also available

Answer (score 14):

```
let A = moment('2020-01-02');
let B = moment('2020-01-01');
let C = moment('2020-01-03');
console.log(A.diff(B, 'days'));// => 1
console.log(A.diff(C, 'days'));// => -1
```

The supported measurements are years, months, weeks, days, hours, minutes, and seconds [momentjs.com](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)

Answer (score 4):

Moment does implement the valueOf() method.  Therefor < <= > >= all can coerce moment into a native type.  If you look at the actual implementations for isAfter or isBefore you'll see that's exactly what they do.

So you can just do `myMoment >= yourMoment`

Answer (score 3):

You could use `isBetween` function that compares one date in a range:

```
let foundDateInRange = moment('2022-01-15').isBetween('2022-01-01', '2022-01-30');
```

[image: Console image using isBetween method]