# Improvement to this code to compare 2 time in format (HH:MM:SS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, time, datetime-comparison

I wrote some code to compare 2 time in string format (HH:MM:SS).

```
var time = new Date();
var current_time_str = time.getHours() + ":" + time.getMinutes() + ":" + time.getSeconds();

var deadline= "16:00:00" //hh:mm:ss
if ( (current_time_str) > (deadline))
{
    console.log("deadline has passed");
}
```

The code actually works by simply comparing the string. However, I am worried if it worked only coincidentally by luck because the string is just an ASCII representation. Are there other ways to compare the 2 time? I am using node.js

Comment: You can use the fantastic Moment.js library; this library has ALL the functions you'll ever need for date-time manipulation. Read about it http://momentjs.com/ and a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/22601120/3102854.

Comment: Thanks. I did look into moment.js. However, there is a problem. moment need objects that come with a date (DD-MM-YYYY). I only need to compare time (HH-MM-SS). Don't think I can use moment.js in this case.

Comment: you can try `var d = new Date(); d.toTimeString();` This will return string with timezone which you can split.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking it's safer to compare two Date objects than it is to compare strings.

You can do something like this:

```
// Get current date/time
var now = new Date();

// Set up deadline date/time
var deadline = new Date();
deadline.setHours(16);
deadline.setMinutes(0);

// Check if the current time is after the deadline
if( now > deadline ) {
    alert('after deadline');
}
else {
    alert('before deadline');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/md63mbpd/