# Comparing time with MomentJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I'm trying to compare a time with momentJS. Here is My script

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var today =moment();
console.log(today.format("hh:mm"));
    if((today.format('D') == (moment().day("Sunday").format('D')) || (today.format('D') == moment().day('Saturday').format('D'))))
        {
            $('.kompensasi').val("100,000");
            $('.chk').hide();
        }
    else{       
        if((today.format("hh:mm") > moment('00:00', 'hh:mm')) && (today.format("hh:mm") < moment('03:00', 'hh:mm')))
                {
                    $('.kompensasi').val("30,000");
                    $('.cekbok').val('');
                }else{
                    $('.cekbok').val('Dapet RO 1');
                    $('.kompensasi').val("0");
                }
        }
});
```

and here is my form

```
<div class="col-sm-7">



            Kompensasi : <input name="dapet" type="text" readonly class="kompensasi" />
           </div>  
    </div>
             <div class="form-group chk">
                      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Ro</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <input type="text" class='cekbok' name='rostatus' />
                      </div>
            </div>
```

from `console.log(today.format("hh:mm"))` i get this resullt `01:44`.

With my script above i always go to the `else`, so is there any way to fix it ?

Here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/s9wfh9ye/33/

My Upated Question

```
    var today =moment();
    var after  = moment(today.format("hh:mm")).isAfter(moment('00:00', "hh:mm"));
    var before = moment(today.format("hh:mm")).isBefore(moment('03:00', "hh:mm"));

        today.format('hh:mm').valueOf() -->02:17

        moment('00:00', 'hh:mm').valueOf() --> 1472058000000

        moment('03:00', 'hh:mm').valueOf() -->1472068800000



   console.log(after); // false

console.log(before); // false
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moment js date time comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600856/moment-js-date-time-comparison)

Comment: `moment('00:00', 'hh:mm')` returns a moment object where as `today.format("hh:mm")` returns a string so you should not be comparing those 2

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Don't compare strings for time. Compare integers instead. Use `.valueOf()` to convert moments to unix timestamp

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To use `==` or `<` or `>` you need to convert the moment to a number. To do that use `.valueOf()`. For example:

```
today.valueOf() < moment('03:00', 'hh:mm').valueOf()
```

However, moment.js also provides methods that are more readable:

```
today.isBefore(moment('03:00', 'hh:mm'))
```

You can use `.isBefore()`, `.isAfter()`, `.isSame()`, `.isSameOrBefore()` etc. Read the documentation for more info: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/

Comment: I'm trrying to use `isAfter` and `IsBefore` please check my updated question

Comment: @YVS1102: Sorry, I had an error in my code. Call `.valueOf()` and `.isAfter()` on the moment object. Not on the string generated by `.format()`. Fixed my code examples