# comparing between sets of time using moment.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I have defined a set of rules.

```
  var rules = [
    {
    time :  "12:00:00 pm",
    time1 :  "01:00:00 pm",
    value:0
    },
   {
    time :  "01:00:00 pm",
    time1 :  "02:00:00 pm",
    value:0
    }, 
    {
    time :  "02:00:00 pm",
        time1 :  "03:00:00 pm",
        value:0
    }, 
    {
    time :  "03:00:00 pm",
        time1 : "04:00:00 pm",
        value:0
    }, {
    time : "04:00:00 pm",
        time1 : "05:00:00 pm",
        value:0
    }
]

module.exports = rules;
```

Now I have got an array of data which consists of time I want to compare the dats with these rules and accordingly increment the value of status in the rules array.
I am using moment.Js to compare but its isAfter() and isBefore functions are not working for me as they should.

```
  _.each(data, function(data){
            // this comes from database where data.start_time consists of time

            console.log(data.start_time); // Mon Oct 03 2016 12:40:36 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)


            var d = moment(data.start_time).format("hh:mm:ss a");
            console.log(d); //12:40:36 pm

            _.each(rules, function(rule){
               console.log(rule.time); //12:00:00 pm

             if(moment(d).isAfter(rule.time))
             {
                // Not able to reach here tried both isAfter
                // isBefore everything.
                console.log("sasa");
             }
         })
       });
```

Also if there is any faster or better way to do these kind of comparision please can you leave a gist below. I will check that out too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to debug your code and have some observations -

1. moment(d).isAfter - here, moment(d) does not have a method called "isAfter". This is a strange thing as it should have this method as per the [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/). I had to call the prototype method like below -

   ```
   var protoType = moment(start_time).__proto__;
   var isafter = protoType.isAfter(rule.time);
   ```

But, this led me to another issue - Maximum call stack size exceeded (**Stack Overflow**ed ;p).

2. Also, when I don't format the date in the way you are formatting (before calling the isAfter method), it works fine. Though I had a dummy value for rule.time variable. Moreover, I had to keep both the dates in the same format.

So, based on the observations, I would suggest you to not rip off the date part from the date by formatting it before comparing, since I guess it is required.

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600856/moment-js-date-time-comparison

Answer (score 0):

[moment().isAfter()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/) as well as [moment().isBefore()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/) methods will take input in the following format.

```
    YYYY-MM-DD Or YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss
```

In your case its in hh:mm:ss format, because of which its returning false everytime. if u want to use this methods then changes your rules array as follows

```
var rules = [
    {
        time: "2016-10-03 12:00:00 pm",
        time1: "2016-10-03 01:00:00 pm",
        value: 0
    },
    {
        time: "2016-10-03 01:00:00 pm",
        time1: "2016-10-03 02:00:00 pm",
        value: 0
    }
]
```

And format the data.start_time as follows

```
    var d = moment(data.start_time).format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss a");
```

This will give you required result.