# ReactJS / JavaScript - finding most recent date from the array of date field while doing selection itself

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table in reactJS with array of items into that table with the following fields

`id`,
`requested_date` & 
`location`

and also i have one more field, which is a date field. so, in the items array i may have one or more items with different `requested_date`.

But in that date field ( which is outside of the array ) should have the latest date out of the array of `requested_date`.

Structure as follows

Item array

`id     requested_date      location
101     2018-03-21          NY
102     2018-03-22          NY
103     2018-03-20          NY`

`Date : 2018-03-22`

In the above structure `Date : 2018-03-22` because `2018-03-22` is the latest `requested_date` from the items array.

Please find my code below.

```
class Details extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.requestedDateChangeonSelectionEvent=this.requestedDateChangeonSelectionEvent.bind(this);
    this.state = { item: props.item };

}
requestedDateChangeonSelectionEvent(dateSelected)
{

    var item = this.state.item;
    var lines = item.order_items;
    if(lines.length == 1)
        {
            var latest = dateSelected; 
            console.log("Length 1");

        }

    else {
        var latest = dateSelected; 
     for(var i=0;i<lines.length;i++) {
         if(moment(lines[i].requested_date) >= moment(latest)) {
             latest=lines[i].requested_ship_date;
             }
         }

    }
       this.state.item.date=latest;
        this.setState({ item: item });

}

render() {
   return (<tbody>{ this.props.items.map((item) => <DetailsItem key={ item.line_id } item={ item } 
                                                        requestedDateChangeonSelectionEvent={ this.props.requestedDateChangeonSelectionEvent }
                                                     />) }

              </tbody>);    
      }
}

class DetailsItem extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleRequestedShipDate = this.handleRequestedShipDate.bind(this);
}

handleRequestedShipDate(e)
{

    var item=this.state.item;
    this.setState({item:item});
    var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    var dateSelected=e.target.value;
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.requestedDateChangeonSelectionEvent(dateSelected);

}
render() {


    return (
            <tr>
            <td><input name="line_number" type="text" value={ this.state.item.line_number } onChange={ his.handleInputChange }/> </td>
            <td><input name="requested_date"  type="date" value={ this.state.item.requested_date } onChange={ (e) => { this.handleRequestedShipDate(e); this.handleInputChange(e); } }  </td>
            <td><input name="source_location" type="text" value={ this.state.item.source_location } onChange={ this.handleInputChange }/> </td>
            </tr>   
             );
    }
}
```

I am trying logic like., while do the selection of `requested_date` itself it should find the latest date and update in the `Date` field.

While I am selecting `request_date` for the very first item its works fine, but when I am selecting for the 2nd and 3rd items, it is not finding with the current selection `request_date,` its go with my previous selection.

Problem in detail :

There is not problem with date comparison. Its happening as per expected. The problem is if i change any date value in the middle of the array or some where., its maintaining previous values and doing the comparison with old value itself. Change is not happening during data selection itself. For example.,

`id     requested_date      location
101     2018-03-21          NY
102     2018-03-22          NY
103     2018-03-20          NY`

Now if i do any change in `102` record like.,

`id     requested_date      location
101     2018-03-21          NY
102     2018-03-19          NY
103     2018-03-20          NY`

am expecting that `2018-03-19` change should happen during selection itself and should compare with other requested_date and should change the latest date to `2018-03--21`.

But, its not happening rather, its maintaining old value`2018-03-22` this value is not changing for that array element during date selection.

Comment: items is a JSON object and this.state.items.order_items is a array?

Comment: There are too many problems with your code. You may want to post a running example to get better help.

Comment: @Demon yes., its JSON array.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding your question very well. If you can create a simple demonstration somewhere (e.g. codesandbox.io), I'd be able to understand it better and try to help.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a duplicate of: [Moment js date time comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600856/moment-js-date-time-comparison).

Try using the `diff` function of momentjs.

When you try and compare two moment objects, JavaScript will only compare their references and not their actual values (JavaScript doesn't know how to compare dates by using `>=`). Thus, use the `diff` function to return the actual difference between dates (which will be in integers and JavaScript knows how to compare integers!)

Comment: OP is using a `>=` when he/she is trying to compare the dates. That may affect the results.

Comment: "JavaScript doesn't know how to compare dates by using >=" – Yes, it does.

Comment: There is no problem with date comparison with JavaScript., I have explained the problem again in more details.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this line in your code `this.state.item.date=latest` ? This could be your culprit.