# javascript function check if date is between

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check if a date of birth entered in a form is between several dates and then populate another field based on the date of birth entered.  I cannot seem to get it to read the dates.

Here is the function

```js
function repeat()
{
 if(document.myform.dob1.value <='09/01/2005' && document.myform.dob1.value >='08/31/2006')
  document.myform.class1.value='Class 1';
 
 else
  document.myform.class1.value='Class 2';
}
```

Here is the form:

```html
<body>
<form name="myform" method="post" action="insert_entries.php">

<table style="width: 139%" align="center">
 <tr>
  <td class="style2" style="width: 166px"><strong>FIRST NAME</strong></td>
  <td class="style2" style="width: 161px"><strong>LAST NAME</strong></td>
  <td class="style2" style="width: 66px"><strong>GENDER</strong></td>
  <td class="style2" style="width: 224px"><strong>DOB</strong></td>
  <td class="style2" style="width: 74px"><strong>CLASS</strong></td>
  <td class="style2" style="width: 104px"><strong>EVENT 1</strong></td>
  <td class="style2" style="width: 104px"><strong>EVENT 2</strong></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="width: 166px">
<input type="text" name="first1" size="35" style="width: 155px" /></td>
  <td style="width: 161px">
<input type="text" name="last1" size="35" style="width: 155px" /></td>
  <td style="width: 66px">
<select name="gender1" class="dropdownbox" id="series id15"style="height: 23px; width: 70px">
<option></option>
<option>M</option>
<option>F</option>
</select></td>
  <td style="width: 224px">
  <input type="date" name="dob1" size="35" onchange = "repeat()" style="width: 155px; height: 27px;" /></td>
  <td style="width: 74px">
<input type="text" name="class1" size="35" style="width: 155px" /></td>
  <td style="width: 104px">
<select name="events1" class="dropdownbox" id="series id"style="height: 23px; width: 104px">
<option></option>
</select> </td>
  <td style="width: 72px">
<select name="events1B" class="dropdownbox" id="series id16"style="height: 23px; width: 104px">
<option></option>
</select> </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

No matter what date I put in the field is always populated with "Class 2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code just put your condition inside `new Date()`. Means replace

```
if(document.myform.dob1.value <='09/01/2005' && document.myform.dob1.value >='08/31/2006')
```

with

```
if(new Date(document.myform.dob1.value) >= new Date('2005-09-01') && new Date(document.myform.dob1.value) <= new Date('2006-08-31'))
```

```js
function repeat()
{
 if(new Date(document.myform.dob1.value) >= new Date('2005-09-01') && new Date(document.myform.dob1.value) <= new Date('2006-08-31'))
  console.log(1);
 else
  console.log(2);
}
```

```html
<body>
<form name="myform" method="post" action="insert_entries.php">

<table style="width: 139%" align="center">
 <tr>
  <td class="style2" style="width: 166px"><strong>FIRST NAME</strong></td>
  <td class="style2" style="width: 161px"><strong>LAST NAME</strong></td>
  <td class="style2" style="width: 66px"><strong>GENDER</strong></td>
  <td class="style2" style="width: 224px"><strong>DOB</strong></td>
  <td class="style2" style="width: 74px"><strong>CLASS</strong></td>
  <td class="style2" style="width: 104px"><strong>EVENT 1</strong></td>
  <td class="style2" style="width: 104px"><strong>EVENT 2</strong></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="width: 166px">
<input type="text" name="first1" size="35" style="width: 155px" /></td>
  <td style="width: 161px">
<input type="text" name="last1" size="35" style="width: 155px" /></td>
  <td style="width: 66px">
<select name="gender1" class="dropdownbox" id="series id15"style="height: 23px; width: 70px">
<option></option>
<option>M</option>
<option>F</option>
</select></td>
  <td style="width: 224px">
  <input type="date" name="dob1" size="35" onchange = "repeat()" style="width: 155px; height: 27px;" /></td>
  <td style="width: 74px">
<input type="text" name="class1" size="35" style="width: 155px" /></td>
  <td style="width: 104px">
<select name="events1" class="dropdownbox" id="series id"style="height: 23px; width: 104px">
<option></option>
</select> </td>
  <td style="width: 72px">
<select name="events1B" class="dropdownbox" id="series id16"style="height: 23px; width: 104px">
<option></option>
</select> </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to parse the dates first as you try to compare with strings, this works just fine for example:

```js
var first = new Date("2018-03-01");
var second = new Date("2018-03-15");
var third = new Date("2018-03-30");

console.log(second > first && second < third); // True
// More examples
console.log(first > second); // False
console.log(first < third); // True
```

Date can even read that ridiculous imperial notation:

```js
console.log(new Date('09/01/2005'))
console.log(new Date('08/31/2006'))
```

Beware of time zones and all that, though.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a duplicate of: [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Your current comparison will just compare strings, which is not a reliable way to compare dates.

Instead, you should use the native `Date` object or try using a library like `momentjs` for dates.

Date comparison with MomentJS: [Moment js date time comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600856/moment-js-date-time-comparison)

Comment: Not true, you can compare dates via comparison operators.

Comment: You're right, I should be clear that JavaScript doesn't know how to compare dates when they are represented as strings.