# Compare the difference between dates with momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have to compare if 15 seconds has passed between the first and the second date which I get from JSON in format: `2019-01-31T10:45:10.000Z` 
I try to make something as:

```
var a = moment(first.date);
var b = moment(second.date);
console.log(a.diff(b, 'seconds'));
```

But it doesn't work correctly at all. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/e6zpduor/ How exactly does it fail? What is the output? Any error messages? Etc.

Comment: You can check how to do it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600856/moment-js-date-time-comparison

Answer (score 0):

```
Can you be more specific??

let a = moment('2018-10-10 10:50:00');
let b = moment('2018-10-10 10:51:00');

var c = moment('2019-01-31T10:50:00.000Z');
var d = moment('2019-01-31T10:51:00.000Z');

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
console.log(b.diff(a, 'seconds'));

console.log(c);
console.log(d);
console.log(d.diff(c, 'seconds'));

// outputs
moment("2018-10-10T10:50:00.000")
moment("2018-10-10T10:51:00.000")
60

moment("2019-01-31T10:50:00.000")
moment("2019-01-31T10:51:00.000")
60
```