# Eliminate array entries based on date

Tags: javascript

I have an array of data similar to this:

```
var items  = [
  { id: 84, "completedDate":"2019-01-26T17:45:07.895Z" },
  { id: 92, "completedDate":"2019-02-26T17:45:07.895Z" }, 
  { id: 123, "completedDate":"2019-03-26T17:45:07.895Z" }, 
  { id: 2353, "completedDate":"2019-04-26T17:45:07.895Z" }
];
```

I would like to return an array with only objects less than 30 days old.

I have tried to filter

```
var filtered = items.filter(function(item) { 
  return moment(item.completedDate) > moment.subtract(30, 'days');  
});
```

Is this what I need to do, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Does it work as expected?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moment js date time comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600856/moment-js-date-time-comparison)

Comment: Do you need moment?  it could probably be done without it if you aren't needing that library for anything else.

Comment: JSON is JavaScript Object Notation, and is a string representation of JavaScript Objects. Where where does the string representation come into this? (i.e. you should not have the `JSON` tag nor reference JSON)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `moment` to compare dates:

```
const compareDate = new Date();
compareDate.setDate(compareDate.getDate() - 30);

const filtered = items.filter(item => new Date(item.completedDate) > compareDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a similar way to do this without `moment`.  here we just get the current day, reset the time back to the start of the day (you may or may not need this for your use case) and then we just use plain JS date objects to compare

```js
var items  = [
  { id: 84, "completedDate":"2019-01-26T17:45:07.895Z" },
  { id: 92, "completedDate":"2019-02-26T17:45:07.895Z" }, 
  { id: 123, "completedDate":"2019-03-26T17:45:07.895Z" }, 
  { id: 2353, "completedDate":"2019-04-26T17:45:07.895Z" }
];

var thirtyDaysAgo = new Date();
thirtyDaysAgo.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
thirtyDaysAgo.setDate(thirtyDaysAgo.getDate() - 30);

var filtered = items.filter(function(item) { 
  var d = new Date(item.completedDate).getTime();
  return d > thirtyDaysAgo;  
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Or, an even smaller filter function (if you don't need IE 11 support) would be:

```js
var filtered = items.filter((item) => new Date(item.completedDate).getTime() > thirtyDaysAgo);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
items.filter( x=> x.completedDate > today.toISOString() );
```

```js
var items  = [
  { id: 84, "completedDate":"2019-01-26T17:45:07.895Z" },
  { id: 92, "completedDate":"2019-02-26T17:45:07.895Z" }, 
  { id: 123, "completedDate":"2019-03-26T17:45:07.895Z" }, 
  { id: 2353, "completedDate":"2019-04-26T17:45:07.895Z" }
];

var today = new Date("2019-04-20T17:45:07.895Z") // or: new Date() 
today = new Date(+today - 30 *86400000)

let r= items.filter( x=> x.completedDate > today.toISOString() );

console.log(r);
```