# Compare one datetime with current datetime

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a date '2019-05-08T22:15:00-0400'. I want to compare this date with the current date and time . if the above date and time is less than current date and time then i have to do something .

My code is :-

```
 if(moment('2019-05-08T13:00:00-0400') < moment()){
       //do something
     }
```

But it returns false .

Comment: print your moment value and see if your given time is correct

Comment: I am getting moment('2019-05-08T13:00:00-0400')  -- "Wed May 08 2019 22:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {} "  and  moment() - Wed May 08 2019 18:41:42 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {} . But for this moment('2019-05-08T13:00:00-0400')  - it is showing time 22.30 . Why ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moment js date time comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600856/moment-js-date-time-comparison)

Comment: actually when i compare moment('2019-05-08T13:00:00-0400')  with current date .It's showing difference of 8.30 hrs. Is there any way to convert both the date into same format.

Answer (score 1):

The original code in the question is correct.  You were running it at a time where it evaluated to false.

(I'm guessing your timezone is something like `+04:30`, explaining the 8:30 difference?)

Answer (score 1):

You can try Date constructor

```
if (new Date('2019-05-08T22:15:00-0400') < new Date()) {
  // Do something
}
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: I have tried this but it's not working .   Actually new Date('2019-05-16T14:15:00-0400') = Thu May 16 2019 23:45:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)  . it's 8:30hrs difference between  14:15:00 and  23:45:00.