# Comparing Moment Date to 'Native' Date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Writing some unit tests where I'm testing some logic that leverages MomentJS.

However, what is the best way to compare dates?

If I look at my dates, they print the following (I'm in EST):

```
// vanilla 
var date = new Date('2018-02-10');

// moment
var mDate = new moment('2018-02-10');

// print contents
console.log(date.toUTCString());    // Fri Feb 09 2018 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
console.log(mDate.toUTCString());   // Sat Feb 10 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)

console.log(date == mDate);         // false
console.log(new Date(date) == new Date(mDate));   //false
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Why not convert both to moment when you need to compare?

Comment: i could, but i'm trying to keep the tests as 'vanilla' as possible.  Conversion is always a possibility, but not my _preferred_ option.

Comment: Did you checked the Timezone-properties of the objects... could be that they are different.

Comment: as you can see above, both are EST

Comment: You need to use `moment.utc()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moment js date time comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600856/moment-js-date-time-comparison)