# Comparing different date formats

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have the following:

```
DATE_FORMAT=YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss
const differenceInDays = require('date-fns/difference_in_days');

const newDateNow = () => {
    const date = new Date();
    return formatDate(date, process.env.DATE_FORMAT);
};

const isValid = (expdate) => {
  today = newDateNow();
  differenceInDays(expdate, today) >= 0;
};
```

Now in a method I have:

```
const c = isValid(a);
```

this returns false, where I would expect true.
Logging the variables I have:

```
today = 2019-12-12 17:55:48
expdate = 2020-10-09T22:00:00.000Z
```

So they have different date formats, which might be the reason `isValid` returns valid even though it should be true (given that `a` is further into the future than `date`).

How can I make this work? Should I perhaps transform the date format of `a` to something similar of `date`? (but how to do that?)

Comment: Maybe this library can help you: https://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: Also, your question may be related to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600856/moment-js-date-time-comparison/22601120

Comment: Why don't you work with the `Date` objects without formatting them to strings? Date objects can be compared easily with the `<` and `>` operators... It is only when you need to display a date that you should worry about formatting.