# Cypress: compare two columns together: column value and date value

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cypress

[image]

I have to check first the value of the status column with new, processing values to then be able to compare the dates.

if I have to compare a new vs processing data, the new date will be greater than the processing date. since the data is sorted by order first by value and then by date ascending. So if I find two values with the usual status I can make the following comparison:

```
    cy.get('#hometable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(6)').each(($e, index, $list) => {
        if (index == 0){time_prev=0}
        time = Math.round(new Date($e.text()).getTime() / 1000)
        assert.isBelow(time_prev, time, 'previous date is below actual')
        time_prev = time
    })


 //so I take the value status
 cy.get('#hometable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(5)').each(($e, index, $list) => {
        const text = $e.text()
        if (text.includes('new')) {
            expect(text).to.eq('\n                                                              new\n                                                           ')

        }
        if (text.includes('processing')) {
            expect(text).to.eq('\n                                                              processing\n                                                           ')
        }

    })
```

I should be able to make the two comparisons together in a single cycle but I have no idea where to start

i give following error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Original answer:

```
let arrayOfColumnOne = [];
let arrayOfColumnTwo = [];

cy.get('#hometable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(6)').each(($e, index, $list) => {
    if (index == 0) {
        time_prev = 0
    }
    time = Math.round(new Date($e.text()).getTime() / 1000)
    assert.isBelow(time_prev, time, 'previous date is below actual')
    time_prev = time
    arrayOfColumnTwo.push(time)
})

//so I take the value status
cy.get('#hometable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(5)').each(($e, index, $list) => {
    const text = $e.text()

    arrayOfColumnOne.push(text)
})
    .then(() => {
        for (let i = 1; i < arrayOfColumnOne; i++) {
            if (!arrayOfColumnTwo[i]) {
                throw new Error('Something is wrong with the array selectors')
            }
            if (arrayOfColumnOne[i].includes('new')) {
                expect(arrayOfColumnOne[i).to.eq('\n                                                              new\n                                                           ')
                assert.isBelow(arrayOfColumnTwo[i - 1], arrayOfColumntwo[i], 'previous date is below actual')
            } else if (text.includes('processing')) {
                expect(text).to.eq('\n                                                              processing\n                                                           ')
                //the assertion you need here
            } else {
                //some other code
            }
        }
    })
```

Editted with suggestion of using [moment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600856/moment-js-date-time-comparison) and [cypress moment](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/moment.html#Syntax), because js round can be unstable

```
let arrayOfColumnTwo = [];

cy.get('#hometable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(6)').each(($e, index, $list) => {
    cy.get($e)
        .parent()
        .find('td:nth-child(5)')
        .then($statusElement =>{
            if($statusElement.text().includes('new')) {
                expect($e.text()).to.eq('\n                                                              new\n                                                            ')
                assert.isBelow(arrayOfColumnTwo[i - 1], arrayOfColumnTwo[i], 'previous date is below actual')
            } else if($statusElement.text().includes('processing')){
                expect($e.text()).to.eq('\n                                                              processing\n                                                           ')
                assert.isAbove(arrayOfColumnTwo[i - 1], arrayOfColumntwo[i], 'previous date is below actual')
            }
        })

    time = Math.round(new Date($e.text()).getTime() / 1000)
    arrayOfColumnTwo.push(time)

})
```

edit 2:

```
let arrayOfColumnTwo = [];

cy.get('#hometable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(6)').each(($e, index, $list) => {
    time = Math.round(new Date($e.text()).getTime() / 1000)
    arrayOfColumnTwo.push(time)
    cy.get($e)
        .parent()
        .find('td:nth-child(5)')
        .then($statusElement =>{
            if($statusElement.text().includes('new')) {
                expect($e.text()).to.eq('\n                                                              new\n                                                            ')
                assert.isBelow(arrayOfColumnTwo[i - 1], arrayOfColumnTwo[i], 'previous date is below actual')
            } else if($statusElement.text().includes('processing')){
                expect($e.text()).to.eq('\n                                                              processing\n                                                           ')
                assert.isAbove(arrayOfColumnTwo[i - 1], arrayOfColumntwo[i], 'previous date is below actual')
            }
        })



})
```

Comment: the data are grouped by status [new, processing] and then sorted by date asc. Therefore the comparison of the dates must be done together with the status field. as you wrote the test fails as before when it comes to compare the third cell given

Comment: what assertion do you need for processing time?

Comment: May be you can use moment data comparsion instead. I editted the suggested answer and will add the status grouping if it works.

Comment: I put another answer Rosen

Comment: I put another answer @Ro

Answer (score 0):

the first answer you gave was logically fine. I've made some changes. I noticed it doesn't enter the then loop

```
let arrayOfColumnOne = [];
let arrayOfColumnTwo = [];

cy.get('#hometable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(6)').each(($e, index, $list) => {
    if (index == 0) {
        time_prev = 0
    }
    time = Math.round(new Date($e.text()).getTime() / 1000)
    arrayOfColumnTwo.push(time)

})

//so I take the value status
cy.get('#hometable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(5)').each(($e, index, $list) => {
    const text = $e.text()
    arrayOfColumnOne.push(text)
}).then(() => {
    for (let i = 1; i < arrayOfColumnOne; i++) {
        if (!arrayOfColumnTwo[i]) {
            throw new Error('Something is wrong with the array selectors')
        }
        if (arrayOfColumnOne[i].includes('new') || arrayOfColumnOne[i].includes('processing')) {
            expect(arrayOfColumnOne[i]).to.eq('\n                                                              new\n                                                           ')
            assert.isBelow(arrayOfColumnTwo[i - 1], arrayOfColumntwo[i], 'previous date is below actual')
        } else if (arrayOfColumnOne[i].includes('processing') && arrayOfColumnOne[i - 1].includes('new')) {
            expect(text).to.eq('\n                                                              processing\n                                                           ')
            assert.isAbove(arrayOfColumnTwo[i - 1], arrayOfColumntwo[i], 'previous date is below actual')

        } else {
            //some other code
        }
    }
})
```

[image]

I don't understand why it doesn't enter the then

Comment: It was my mistacke. For that part it doesnt need to be in a then statement, because we have stored the values in reference type object

Comment: I would chain it of cy.log() so i can know when it starts after collecting all the data

Comment: if I leave the for without the then it makes no assertion. If I leave a cy.log inside the loop in order to print the elements it doesn't print anything @RosenMihaylov

Comment: cy.log('startLoop).then(()=>{loop})

Answer (score 0):

```
cy.log('startLoop').then(()=>{
            for (let i = 1; i < arrayOfColumnOne; i++) {
                if (!arrayOfColumnTwo[i]) {
                    throw new Error('Something is wrong with the array selectors')
                }
                if (arrayOfColumnOne[i].includes('new') && arrayOfColumnOne[i-1].includes('new')) {
                    expect(arrayOfColumnOne[i]).to.eq('\n                                                              new\n                                                           ')
                    assert.isBelow(arrayOfColumnTwo[i - 1], arrayOfColumntwo[i], 'previous date is below actual')
                } else if (arrayOfColumnOne[i].includes('processing') && arrayOfColumnOne[i - 1].includes('processing')) {
                    expect(text).to.eq('\n                                                              processing\n                                                           ')
                    assert.isBelow(arrayOfColumnTwo[i - 1], arrayOfColumntwo[i], 'previous date is below actual')
                } else {
                    expect(text).to.eq('\n                                                              processing\n                                                           ')
                    assert.isAbove(arrayOfColumnTwo[i - 1], arrayOfColumntwo[i], 'previous date is below actual')
                }
            }
        })
```

[image]

does not print anything

Comment: Ok Let me look tru my documentation and look for another answer. Does the moment comparsion work?

Answer (score 0):

```
let arrayOfColumnTwo = [];

cy.get('#hometable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(6)').each(($e, index, $list) => {
    cy.get($e)
        .parent()
        .find('td:nth-child(5)')
        .then($statusElement =>{
            if(index==0) {
            }
            else if($statusElement.text().includes('new')) {
                assert.isBelow(arrayOfColumnTwo[index - 1], arrayOfColumnTwo[index], 'previous date is below actual')
            } else{
                assert.isAbove(arrayOfColumnTwo[index - 1], arrayOfColumntwo[index], 'previous date is above actual')
            }
        })

    time = Math.round(new Date($e.text()).getTime() / 1000)
    arrayOfColumnTwo.push(time)

})
```

[image]

I have simplified the function so that it only compares dates. When it comes to compare the processing date of this error