# how to compare date and time using MomentJs and React

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using MomentJs in a ReactJs project. I am trying to compare the date and time
How can I compare the time. use the remindTime object

Im am currently doing the follow however does not work because it is looking at the remindTime object and not the date and time

```
moment() >= moment(remindTime) ? true : false
```

```
const remindTime =
        {
            _id: new ObjectId("614fa5ed18b365aa83099183"),
            title: 'Third Message',
            description: 'Item 3',
            remindTime: { date: '2021-09-26', time: '7:43:21 pm' },
            isComplete: false,
        }
```

Basically I want to know if the current time is great or equal to the date and time in the remindTime object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moment js date time comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600856/moment-js-date-time-comparison)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use  [moment query functions]:https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/

Take into account that moment works with specific param formats, so you cannot give it standalone objects.

Considered that, you'll need the `diff` function and parse apropiately  `remindTime.date` and `remindTime.time`:

To get the difference in milliseconds, use moment#diff like you would use moment#from.

```
var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
var b = moment([2007, 0, 28]);
a.diff(b) // 86400000
```

And to get the difference in another unit of measurement, pass that measurement as the second argument.

```
var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
var b = moment([2007, 0, 28]);
a.diff(b, 'days') // 1
```

An example for this could be:

```
//given
const remindTime1 =
        {
            _id: new ObjectId("614fa5ed18b365aa83099183"),
            title: 'Third Message',
            description: 'Item 3',
            remindTime: { date: '2021-09-26', time: '7:43:21 pm' },
            isComplete: false,
        }
// and also given another object for comparing times and dates

const remindTime2 =
        {
            _id: new ObjectId("614fa5ed18b365aa83099183"),
            title: 'Third Message',
            description: 'Item 3',
            remindTime: { date: '2020-09-28', time: '9:50:21 pm' },
            isComplete: false,
        }

const parseDate1= remindTime.remindTime.date.split('-');
//this returns [2021,09,28]
const parseDate2= remindTime2.remindTime.date.split('-');
//this returns [2021,09,26]

var a = moment(parseDate1);
var b = moment(parseDate2);

//then you can compare dates in different ways sush us:

a.diff(b, 'days')   // 1
a.diff(b) // 86400000 => this is miliseconds
a.diff(b, 'years');   // 1
```

Also it could be easier to think that diff is a kind of minus operator:

```
a.diff(b) // a - b < 0
b.diff(a) // b - a > 0
```

Hope it works, for further info please check this out: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/

Comment: I am trying to figure out the best method to compare in regards to the data object that I have. how to put the object into moment so that it can compare

Comment: As long as I know, moment only accepts dates, not objects. So, in you code you will always have to give `remindTime.date` or parse apropiatelly `remindTime.date` and `remindTime.time` in order to give moment an appropiate param.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to also provide an example using the provide data. That would be very helpful

Comment: Okay, done. Hope it works.